# extract only words from sentence which includees numbers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i am using the TesseractOCR to read a receipt and i have managed to extract the text from the receipt line by line e.g

```
2 melon            £3.00
1 lime             £1.50
5 chicken wings    £10.00
```

But now, for each line, i would like to extract the item name(melons, lime, chicken wings), then the integer and then the float all sepearately line by line. I have googled a lot and have written this in ruby using regex but cant figure out how to do it in swift. I have figured out the float and integer part just not the words only part.

a link to an answer already would be great or an answer. thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have solved this using regex in Ruby, the solution in Swift is similar. First let's define some helper functions since `NSRegularExpression` still deals in `NSRange` units:

```
extension String {
    var fullRange: NSRange {
        return NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)
    }

    subscript(range: NSRange) -> String {
        let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
        let endIndex   = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.length)

        return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
    }
}
```

And the code:

```
let text =
    "2 melon            £3.00\n" +
    "1 lime             £1.50\n" +
    "5 chicken wings    £10.00"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\d+)\\s+(.+?)\\s+£([\\d\\.]+)$", options: [.anchorsMatchLines])

regex.enumerateMatches(in: text, options: [], range: text.fullRange) { result, flag, stop in
    if let result = result {
        let r1 = result.rangeAt(1)
        let r2 = result.rangeAt(2)
        let r3 = result.rangeAt(3)

        print("quantity = \(text[r1]), item = \(text[r2]), price = \(text[r3])")
    }
}
```

Comment: i had no idea regex was available for swift. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

use componentSeparatedByString

```
let a = "5 Chicken Wing"
let b = a.componentSeparatedByString(" ") //meaning space
let b0 = b[0] //5
let b1 = b[1] //Chicken
let b2 = b[2] //Wing
```